# trigger function for back button in browser by javascript

Tags: javascript

For Example, if any running any web page and wanted to go back, i unable get any function on click on the back button in the browser. Does javascript provide any function for trigger the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `history.back()` on most browsers.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp